# Prove there is a rational on the open interval $(a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis

Where $a$ and $b$ are reals.

I want to use $(a+b)/2$ but I don't know how I can assure this is rational. I feel like I can do it via this approach but I'm not sure how.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are real, then $(a+b)/2$ isn't necessarily rational.

Comment: I know, that's my problem. That's what I said in the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The trick is to use $\Bbb R$'s Archimedian property. Suppose $0 < a < b$ for now. Let $n$ be a large enough natural number such that $1/n < b-a$. Now let $m$ be the smallest natural number such that $m/n > a$. Now conclude that $m/n < b$, and we're done with this case.

If $a \leq 0 \leq b$, you take $0$ to be the rational.

If $a < b < 0$, you apply the result proven above for the interval $(-b,-a)$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a + \epsilon = b$ , then there exists large enough $m \in \mathbb N$ such that $\epsilon \cdot m > 10$. 
 Now we look at the interval $(ma , mb)$, you can easily verify that $mb - ma > 10$

This implies there is a **nautral number** $n \in (ma, mb)$.

(This is a different approach to the archimedean property of the real axis)